# Flot charts bar to be shown with arrows indicating rise and fall

Tags: flot

I have a  bar chart in flot and i want to have up or down arrows besides each data bar, as an indicator. Basically i want to add annotations to a flot chart.
I am looking for a chart like below,

[image]

Comment: A bit of code samples would be nice...

Comment: I am using the basic example given [here](http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-bar-chart.html) .

Comment: placeholder.append('<div style="position:absolute;left:' + ((largestLabel*6) + (right + 20)) + 'px;top:' + (top - 10) + 'px;color:#666;font-size:large"><img src="images/ups.png" alt="image" /></div>');

This code line will add the desired image or anything you put in the mentioned div.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any HTML element to flot chart by manipulating DOM, below is a link that illustrates how this can be done,

http://www.isquery.com/devel/jquery/flot/examples/annotating.html

Make the below modifications to the snippet in the above link,

```
var o = plot.pointOffset({ x: 1, y: 15});
placeholder1.append('<div style="position:absolute;left:' + (o.left + 4) +     'px;top:' + o.top + 'px;color:#666;font-size:large"><img src="images/UpArrow.png" alt="image" /></div>');
```